# Function.Match in a Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, match

I am trying to match a value from a cell `(grid_2.range "A1")` and `grid_2.range("B1")` with a **column P on a sheet named grid_2 ("Grid2")** to copy all the row where there value is located. Therefore, I will need to check on my data and copy/paste the entire row to another sheet maned **grid**. But for some reason my code loops but only find the match and copy and paste once.

```
Sub new_copyPaste()

    Dim targetSh As Worksheet
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    
    lastRow = grid.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
    
    For i = 3 To grid_2.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
        Position = WorksheetFunction.Match(grid_2.Range("A1"), Worksheets("Grid2").Columns(16), 0)
          If grid_2.Cells(i, 16).Value = grid_2.Range("A1") Then
           Worksheets("Grid2").Rows(Position).Copy
           grid.Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next i
    
        
    For i = 3 To grid_2.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    Position = WorksheetFunction.Match(grid_2.Range("B1"), Worksheets("Grid2").Columns(16), 0)
    
        If grid_2.Cells(i, 16).Value = grid_2.Range("B1") Then
           Worksheets("Grid2").Rows(Position).Copy
           grid.Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Maybe do you know what I am doing wrong?

I thought about using VLookup, but after researching, it seems that function match would be more appropriate.
I am open for suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match only returns the first match and is not needed here:

```
Sub new_copyPaste()

    
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 3 To grid_2.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
          If grid_2.Cells(i, 16).Value = grid_2.Range("A1") Then
           Worksheets("Grid2").Rows(i).Copy
           lastRow = grid.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
           grid.Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next i
    
    For i = 3 To grid_2.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
        If grid_2.Cells(i, 16).Value = grid_2.Range("B1") Then
           Worksheets("Grid2").Rows(i).Copy
           lastRow = grid.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
           grid.Range("A" & lastRow).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```